# How to add white space before an item?

Tags: spacing, lists

How to add white space before an item ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Dqfnqsdf qsdfjdqs qsdjqsd qsdmqsjdqsd qsd qsdqsdq.
\begin{itemize}
\item One.
\item Two.
\end{itemize}
Dqfnqsdf qsdfjdqs qsdjqsd qsdmqsjdqsd qsd qsdqsdq.
\begin{enumerate}
\item One E.
\item Two e.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: before horizontally or vertically ?

Comment: @Tarass, horizontally.

Comment: wouldn't this be nesting? Just put an `itemize` into another `itemize`. If you want to have bullets for the second level as well, you may search this side for that.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, I've a long report in which I don't want to replace many of itemizes and enumerates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\setlength\leftmargini{3cm}

\begin{document}
Dqfnqsdf qsdfjdqs qsdjqsd qsdmqsjdqsd qsd qsdqsdq.
\begin{itemize}
\item One.
\item Two.
\end{itemize}
Dqfnqsdf qsdfjdqs qsdjqsd qsdmqsjdqsd qsd qsdqsdq.
\begin{enumerate}
\item One E.
\item Two e.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that've only worked on enumerate!!

Comment: @AmurayuYukiko as shown in the image, it applies to itemize and enumerate

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear, where you want the white-space, so I add three possible answers. The first one shows the typical nesting, which should be the preferred solution if you intent to indent only single items. I guess, the last one is, what you want. In order to change all lists, see Davids answer.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item One.
\begin{itemize}
\item Indented item.
\item Indented second item.
\end{itemize}
\item Two.
\end{itemize}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\begin{enumerate}
\item One E.
\item \hspace{20pt} Two e.
\end{enumerate}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\begin{itemize}
\item One.
\setlength{\itemindent}{+25pt}
\item Two.
%\setlength{\itemindent}{0pt} % if you want to go back on prior level
%\item Three.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]